# Get data with route parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

How can i pass $id parameter from view to route ? I dont know well laravel .just i am learning.

my controller

```
class YayinController extends Controller
{
public function index(){

    return view ('yayin.canli');
}

public function hamleler($id){


   $notations=Notasyon::where('id',$id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    if($id==$notations->id){
        $lastgame=$notations->hamle;
        return response()->json($lastgame);

    }
   }
  }
```

I want to receive data according to this id value and send it to view1.

if the id of the database data is the same as the id of the parameter, the data will continue to be pulled in 10 seconds. I want to do this with the data script code (in view getjsondata ())

Routes

```
   Route::get('/canli-yayin/','YayinController@index');
   Route::get('/canli-yayin/hamleler/{id?}','YayinController@hamleler');
```

canli.blade.php

```
 function getjsondata() {



 $.get("{{URL::To('canli-yayin/hamleler/')}}", function(data) {


       if(data) { 
 document.getElementById("notasyon").innerHTML=document.getElementById("notasyon").innerHTML+data+" ";

}
 else {
      alert('error');
       }
       });
       }

$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(getjsondata,3000)

    })
```

Comment: Hacı id tam olarak nereden gelip, nereye gidiyor ? Sen controllerdan viewe id mi yolluyorsun, yoksa view de yer alan bir formdan controllera mı id yolluyorsun ?

Comment: Hacı id' nin view den gelmesi gerek. view'de veri alma işlemini Setinterval fonksiyonu ile 3 saniyede bir yapacağım. İStediğim şey sürekli aynı veriyi ya zadırmamak view içinde. bunuda, Controllerda id değerlerini karşılaştırdıktan sonra aynı veri değilse çekeyim. Bunun içinde id değerini viewe geldikten sonra 1 artırmam lazım sanırım.

Comment: viewin ilgili kısmını eklesene bi soruya

Comment: Hocam bende doğru düzgün js-jquery yok, yanlış bir bilgilendirme yapmak istemem, ama url to kullanıyorsun orada {{URL::To('canli-yayin/hamleler'.$id)}} diyerek gönderemiyor musun ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the helpers like `route()` for named routes or [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url) for any route:

```
{{ url('canli-yayin/hamleler', [$id]) }}
```

In the `hamleler()` method you need to get `$id`:

```
public function hamleler($id)
```

Answer (score 0):

**normal form submit**

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('/canli-yayin/hamleler', [$id])}}">
```

**form submit using ajax**

```
var id = "getting it from blade"

      $.ajax({
          url:'/canli-yayin/hamleler/'+id,
          type:"POST",
          success:function(response){  
          },
        });
```

**web routes**

```
Route::get('/canli-yayin/hamleler/{id?}','YayinController@hamleler');
```

**controller**

```
class YayinController extends Controller
{
public function index(){

    return view ('yayin.canli');
}

    public function hamleler($id){

        dd($id);
        $notations=Notasyon::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $lastgame=$notations->hamle;
        return response()->json($lastgame);

         }

    }
```

Comment: Can I change the id value in the view and send it back to the Controller?

Comment: Yes you can change it.

Comment: instead of [$id] use ['number']